Cost path avoiding distance on specified slope using ArcGIS Pro
I'm trying to find a least cost path that avoids travelling more than a distance of 2 m up and over a slope of 45 degrees or greater.
Any ideas on how to do this using ArcGIS Pro?

Please decide whether it is QGIS or ArcGIS Pro that you wish to ask about in this particular question.

So traveling 1 m over 45º is ok, but >2 should never happen?

2 m or less is OK, technically the distance would take into account both rise and run.  For a bit more background, I collected 7 km x 2 km of LiDAR data with a drone for this analysis, 40 GB of data. I created a slope map and reduced the resolution to 2 m pixels to attempt to take into account the 2 m slope travel limit, although this is horizontal distance only. Not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

Use path distance. Leave cost surface blank and use vertical factor with your DEM. It will compute cosdiistance and backlink rasters - inputs for path calculations
